# Control-M job Scheduling

Tags: control-m

I have one job that is scheduled using a calendar. I need to create a dummy job that should get scheduled for all other days except the day Job 1 is running.

Can anybody please explain how I can achieve this in Control-M.

Answer (score 0):

**You'll have to make a custom suit**.

> At the moment, there is no native functionality that allows you to do
>   something like this, so you will have to do your own implementation.

Following the description of your case the Job Dummy you mention should be of another type (not Dummy).

An alternative solution might consider the following:

1. *Job1* is executed according to the regular calendar with the name **CALENDAR1**.
2. The *Job2* is executed every day and it is the Job that schedules the target job named *Job3*.
3. The *Job2* executes a query on the Calendar table to the Control-M/EM database by filtering by calendar name **CALENDAR1**, the **year** and **month**. Then extract from the resulting string the position according to the **day** of execution, if the value is "N" means that the **Job1** is not scheduled so we would have to order the *Job3* via **ctmorder** utility.

I will try to include the code of the solution if you still require it.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Say Date is 16 Jan then  You can create two calendars and say Calendar 1 Holiday - 16th Jan and Calendar2 with that one date which is 16th jan
then two instances of Job keep Calendar 1 and other with Calendar 2 will help

Also if you have with Holiday +1 or Holiday +2 then you can use advance scheduling options in control M using Shift property using Order day like this - using this u can reuse the same calendar object

Hope this helps!